# How to show files of a certain name in a panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

`cmd+p` shows a list of files matching a certain name.

Is it possible to persist the result and show it in a dedicated panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes, but in a slightly different format

Go to the "Search" tab, enable regex (the square with an asterisk in the first input box), type `^` (means "start of file/line" depending on regex flags), type the name of the file (use asterisks on both sides for better search), and exclude things like `node_modules` and `.git`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't support fuzzy search (like if you type "vsc", <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> could find a file named "visual studio code.txt" but this can't), but you can get around that with an asterisk between each character.

[image]